# Pivot function producing nulls and I need zeros

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot-table, oracle-apex

I'm looking for a more efficient way to write this code.  The problem is that the pivot table produces null values and I need zeros instead so that I can add the columns together to make a total column.  Thank you!

```
    select coll_group, sub_group, collector, 
    M0,
    M1,
    M2,
    M3,
    M4,
    M5
    M6,
    M7,
    M8,
    M9,
    M10,
    M11,
    M12,
    (M1+M2+M3+M4+M5+M6+M7+M8+M9+M10+M11+M12) Total
    from(
    select coll_group, sub_group, collector,
        case when "0_M" is null then 0 else "0_M" end M0 , 
        case when "1_M" is null then 0 else "1_M" end M1 , 
        case when "2_M" is null then 0 else "2_M" end M2 , 
        case when "3_M" is null then 0 else "3_M" end M3 , 
        case when "4_M" is null then 0 else "4_M" end M4 ,
        case when "5_M" is null then 0 else "5_M" end M5 , 
        case when "6_M" is null then 0 else "6_M" end M6 , 
        case when "7_M" is null then 0 else "7_M" end M7 ,
        case when "8_M" is null then 0 else "8_M" end M8 , 
        case when "9_M" is null then 0 else "9_M" end M9 , 
        case when "10_M" is null then 0 else "10_M" end M10 , 
        case when "11_M" is null then 0 else "11_M" end M11 , 
        case when "12_M" is null then 0 else "12_M" end M12                
        from
    (select * from (
      select coll_group, sub_group, collector, low_activity_days,
        months_between(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), month) as month_offset
      from low_activity_days_collect_t
      where month >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -13)
      and month < trunc(sysdate, 'MM')
    ) src
    pivot (sum(low_activity_days) as M
      for month_offset in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12))))
```

Comment: Use coalesce or nvl

Comment: perhaps `sum(coalesce(low_activity_days,0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NVL(0_M,0) M0` instead of `case when "0_M" is null then 0 else "0_M" end M0` and so on...

Comment: I've got a follow up question, if I may be so bold.  The column names need to be a rolling twelve months.  So, M0 needs to be Apr17, M1 would be Mar17 and so on.  So, each month when I run this query, the names would update automatically.  Is there a way to do that within the query itself?

Comment: Something like this (pseudocode): `case when year_month = current_year_month then value end value_M0`, `case when year_month = current_year_month+1 then value end value_M1` ... `from table where year_month between current_year_month and current_year_month+12`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the sum of null and 1 is 1, so why worry about it?